# Does varchar(max) = varchar?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I noticed that I can write

```
SELECT CAST(Min(mynumber) AS VARCHAR(Max))+'mystring' AS X
```

as

```
SELECT CAST(Min(mynumber) AS VARCHAR)+'mystring' X
```

Will I regret leaving out the (Max) parameter?

Comment: In general you should not be using varchar (max). It should be used rarely and only if you expect more than the 8000 charcters a regular varchar can contain. Define varchars with the number of characters you think they should contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a varchar's lenght is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When it is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

See: [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

I feel that it is poor practice to code without specifying a length for varchar.

Answer (score 8):

You'll regret it in the (unlikely) situation that `MAX(mynumber)` has more than 30 characters:

> [When *n* is not specified when using the `CAST` and `CONVERT` functions, the default length is 30.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

Comment: Always a good idea to define the number of characters in a situation where you are casting. Or if you are defining a variable (where the default is 1 for varchar). This should just be second nature.

Answer (score 3):

VARCHAR(MAX) should be used for Large Objects.It uses the normal datapages until the content actually fills 8k of data. When overflow happens, data is stored as old TEXT, IMAGE and a pointer is replacing the old content. 
Varchar is for Variable-length, non-Unicode character data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. Max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes and varchar (Max) should not ever be used for fields that expect smaller data as it has indexing issues.